# Baking particle system particles (not mantaflow) to a mesh object shape

Tags: mesh, particles, baking

Mantaflow in Blender has a function "Bake to mesh" which bakes the baked fluid particles to a fluid mesh.

Is there a way that I can create a particle system, and also bake the particles (not hair) to a mesh object too?

My ideal would be using fluid particle physics to simulate a fluid flow, then baking the particles to a mesh object so that it will actually look like fluid.

How can I do this?

Comment: If I remember correctly, there was an addon called *cubesurfer* to mesh a particle system.

Comment: Is it available for 2.79?